# NameError: global name 'END' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I have found this code about scrollbar is just working fine.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(10000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

I try to use it in my code like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,den):
        self.tklist() 
        #in my code, tklist is not called here. I called it here to minimize the code
        #there are stuff in here also

    def tklist(self):
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(den)
        self.lst1 = tk.Listbox(den, selectmode="SINGLE", width="100", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        for i in range(1000):
            self.lst1.insert(END, str(i))
        self.lst1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        scrollbar.config(command=lst1.yview)

den = tk.Tk()
den.title("Search")

inter = interface(den)

den.mainloop()
```

But when I ran above code, I got an error on insertion line.

```
NameError: global name 'END' is not defined
```

By the way, I tried to find documentation and [a link from effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) is the closest I got but still couldn't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`END`, `LEFT`, and `BOTH` all reside in the `tkinter` namespace.  Thus, they need to be qualified by placing `tk.` before them:

```
for i in range(1000):
    self.lst1.insert(tk.END, str(i))
self.lst1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=lst1.yview)
```

Or, you could import them explicitly if you want:

```
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
```

Comment: The other option is to simply use the literal strings `"end"`, `"left"` or `"both"`. I've never quite understood why tkinter made contants for these strings.

Answer (score 0):

use "end" instead of END

```
from tkinter import *
self.lst1.insert("end", str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code is working because you imported * from tkinter, but in the second code you imported tkinter as tk. so you need to use tk.END

```
def tklist(self):
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(den)
    self.lst1 = tk.Listbox(den, selectmode="SINGLE", width="100", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    for i in range(1000):
        self.lst1.insert(tk.END, str(i))
    self.lst1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command=lst1.yview)
```