# NameError: name 'BOTTOM' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I have:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Button, Tk, Pack
gui = Tk()
bottomFrame = Frame(gui)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

gui.mainloop()
```

I get an undefined name `'BOTTOM'` error when I try and run my program. If I use:

```
from tkinter import *
```

It works, but I've read that using `import *` isn't recommended. In fact, flake8 gives me a bunch of warnings if I try.

The Pack class should be giving me the necessary methods and options but it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: global name 'END' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199858/nameerror-global-name-end-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BOTTOM` is an attribute of the `tkinter` module.
You need to either explicitly import it, or import `tkinter` and then refer to `tkinter.BOTTOM`.

First solution, to stick with what you already have:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Tk, BOTTOM

gui = Tk()
bottomFrame = Frame(gui)
bottomFrame.pack(BOTTOM)

gui.mainloop()
```

Second solution, which I personally prefer: import only the `tkinter` module, and specify the module name everywhere:

```
import tkinter as tk

gui = tk.Tk()
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(gui)
bottomFrame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

gui.mainloop()
```

Third solution, that I wouldn't recommend but that does exist: since `tkinter.BOTTOM` is actually equal to `"bottom"`, you can simply do:

```
bottomFrame.pack(side="bottom")
```

---

Additionally, it is totally useless to import the `Pack` class, since you should be accessing it exclusively through the `Widget.pack` method.
Besides, you're right to avoid `from tkinter import *` statement, so keep on not using it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try and use the second method. It seems cleaner.

Comment: If either of the above codes run without a `mainloop`, then the codes are _not_ standalone. Add `gui.mainloop()` as the last line for a more consistent program.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't all the code. I do have it at the end. This is just the snippet I was having trouble with.

Comment: @Nae I'm not sure whether this is relevant to the problem, but I agree it's better if the code can be executed right away; I'm editing this.